# android convert bitmap to bufferedinputstream

Tags: android, bitmap, bufferedinputstream

Newb question;

I've got a bitmap in memory;

```
Private Bitmap MyPicture;
```

Then later, I fill that MyPicture from imager from the camera. I need to upload that photo using the FTP client from the apache commons.

```
fcon.storeFile("filename", new BufferedInputStream(MyPicture.????));
```

But the apache want a BufferedInputStream. How do I convert the memory Bitmap to a memory stream?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what I was looking for;

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
si.Image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());
```

The last line was the missing link...

Comment: Hey @Lectare, could you please include a complete code snippet? I have no idea what "si" is, and how your original snippet goes together with this one.

Comment: @SkyKelsey, si.Image is a Bitmap type

Comment: Why do you need to `compress` it? You compress it to a `JPEG` but what if the image is a gif? Does it lose all alpha values if the image is a PNG? What does that actually do?

Answer (score 0):

Converting the bitmap to a byte array is as easy as:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
MyPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
baos.toByteArray();
```

And then you can create a `BufferedInputStream`to write the bytes to your file.

Comment: Is the bitmap type allways uncompressed?

Comment: Can't get it to work; BufferedInputStream expects a InputStream, which baos is not...